# Why are algebraic schemes called algebraic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview, terminology, schemes

In scheme theory, an algebraic scheme is the data of a scheme + a morphism of finite type to the spectrum of a field. Where does the term "algebraic scheme" come from? It does not seem intuitive to me (to me all schemes are equally algebraic, others may have a different opinion). Are there any historical accounts regarding this matter?

Here is [one mention](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2197483/680178) of the category of algebraic schemes without an explicit reference to the base (though it appears that in that terminology all schemes are understood to come with a morphism to the spectrum of a field). In [the Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06LF), they use "algebraic $k$-schemes" (with $k$ being a field).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi that is kind of funny, I did not think of that. Maybe so, maybe so.

Comment: It's not a great terminology, and I actually never saw it (or didn't pay attention). +1 if you prefer "scheme of finite type over a field".

Comment: @YCor reassuring to see some people of similar opinion.

Comment: But actually now that I'm looking, I can see in Grothendieck (1960) http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1958-1960__5__193_0.pdf the use of "schéma algébrique sur $A$" (algebraic scheme over $A$), where $A$ does not have to be a field (yet it seems to mean finite type).

Comment: In the context of field extensions, finite type does not imply algebraic.

Comment: finite type schemes over a field are exactly the schemes which correspond to  algebraic varieties, so algebraic scheme = algebraic variety. I think that is the reason for the name.

Comment: @GLe interesting theory indeed. Where I come from, varieties are usually separated, though I understand it can be different elsewhere.

Comment: Varieties are separated, but so were schemes back when this terminology was introduced. Then, schemes=preschemes+separated.

Comment: @SamirCanning OK, then change the question. Why are "algebraic preschemes" called algebraic?

Comment: The reason is that an algebraic scheme over a field can be covered by a finite number of spectra of finitely generated algebras. Those affine schemes that arise as the spectrum of a finitely generated algebra over a field are called algebraic, and the intuition behind this is that they are defined by a finite set of polynomials in a finite number of symbols. I think this terminology and point of view is common in the context of group schemes,  see for example the notes of J.S. Milne

Comment: "finite type schemes over a field are exactly the schemes which correspond to algebraic varieties" - No: they also have to be reduced and separated (and some people also assume irreducible).

Comment: @Qfwfq Yes, the one you cite appears to be the most common definition. I was following the definition of alg. variety given in Qing Liu's book. It doesn't change anything for the purpose of answering the question. Algebraic varieties (whatever you want them to be) and algebraic schemes share the "algebraic" adjective because they can be covered by finitely many spectra of finitely generated algebras.

Comment: @GLe: yep, sorry. I personally woldn't call "variety" something nonreduced, but as you say it's just terminology..

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Is it not a variant of the Nullstellensatz that a finite type field extension is finite, hence algebraic?

Comment: @red_trumpet It depends on whether "finite type" means as field extension or ring extension. In the second case we have algebraicity by the Nullstellensatz, but not in the first case.